# Un-optioning an optioned Option

Tags: scala, monads, flatten, scala-option

Say I have a `val s: Option[Option[String]]`. It can thus have the following values:

`Some(Some("foo"))`
`Some(None)`
`None`

I want to reduce it so that the first becomes `Some("foo")` while the two others become `None`. Obviously there are many ways to accomplish this, but I'm looking for a simple, perhaps built-in, less-than-one-liner.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

<strike>It's a shame that `flatten` doesn't exist.  It should.</strike>

Flatten does exist now.

As before,

```
s getOrElse None
```

(in addition to the other answers) will also do the same thing.

Comment: seems to exist now: 
    scala> Some(Some(1)).flatten
    res10: Option[Int] = Some(1)

Comment: it seems [flatten has made it into cats as well](https://non.github.io/cats//tut/monad.html)

Comment: @Alexy when I call `flatten` on an object like `Some(Some(Some(1)))` I get `Cannot prove that Any <:< Option[B]`

Answer (score 16):

You could use [**scalaz**](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/) `join` to do this, as this is one of the *monadic* operations:

```
doubleOpt.join
```

Here it is in the REPL:

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> some(some("X")).join
res0: Option[java.lang.String] = Some(X)

scala> some(none[String]).join
res1: Option[String] = None

scala> none[Option[String]].join
res3: Option[String] = None
```

It's available to anything with a typeclass instance for a Monad.

Comment: I've a map like `val map = Map("a"->Some(Some(1)), "b"->2)`, when I call `map.get("a").join` I see `could not find implicit value for parameter ev: scalaz.Liskov.<~<[Any,Option[B]]`

Answer (score 14):

```
s.flatten
```

followed by a bunch of characters to get me up to the minimum that stackoverflow allows

Comment: That's what I what thinking of, but it returns an Iterable and not an Option.

Comment: Hmm, that's very odd.  Why would they do that?  Try s.flatmap(x=>x) instead.

Comment: One could also write `s flatMap identity`.

Comment: Summarizing the above: `List(Some(Some("foo")), Some(None), None) map { _ flatMap identity }` yields `List[Option[java.lang.String]] = List(Some(foo), None, None)`, which I think is what Knut (the OP and the first non-polar-bear-cub named "Knut" I've heard of) wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I think the conversion to the Iterable is just fine.  Use these steps to go from `Option[Option[String]` to a single `Option[String]`

```
s.flatten.headOption
```

(which returns `Option[String]`)

Answer (score 1):

You might use flatMap like the following:

```
val options = List(Some(Some(1)), Some(None), None)
options map (_ flatMap (a => a))
```

This will map the `List[Option[Option[Int]]]` to a `List[Option[Int]]`.

If you just have an Option you can use it as following:

```
val option = Some(Some(2))
val unzippedOption = option flatMap (b => b)
```

This will flatten your `Option[Option[Int]]` to `Option[Int]`.

Answer (score -4):

Well, I actually don't understand how come it could be just None (the third case). If it can really be also just None, then I would vote for Rex Kerr's answer, otherwise just .get would be enough:

```
scala> Some(Some("foo")).get
res0: Some[java.lang.String] = Some(foo)

scala> Some(None).get
res1: None.type = None
```

Comment: It can be `None` because it's an `Option`!

Comment: Yeah, but this is Option inside Option ... so I would expect it's Some(Some("something")) for positive result and Some(None) for negative result. What third state describes just None then? Well if the problem is in 3-state logic, only then it makes sense.

Comment: It's kind of equivalent to a future: `Some(Some(X))` is a calculated value, `Some(None)` indicates the future has finished with no value and `None` indicates there future has not returned

Comment: Option[String] is a String or not.  Let's write that as String + 1, meaning it can be any String or 1 other thing.  An Option[Option[String]] then is (String + 1) + 1, or String + 2.  Which is to say it's a String or it's one of two other things.  In other words Option[Option[String]] is isomorphic to Either[Boolean, String].  I think the later structure indicates more clearly that it either the computation is successful in producing a string or may fail in two different ways.

Comment: Hehe, nice explanation -- "There are many ways to fail, but only one to succeed." :-)