# Is there a more idiomatic way of getting IO[Option[A]] from Option[IO[Option[A]] then using sequence and mapping join?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm running into quite a few places where I have something akin to

```
def f(s: String): Option[Long] = ...
def g(l: Long): IO[Option[Wibble]] = ...

val a: IO[Option[Wibble]] = f(param).flatMap(g).sequence.map(_.join)
```

Seeing the `.sequence.map(_.join)` repeated over and over is starting to bother me.  Is there a more idiomatic way of accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: Are you sure about the types in the example? g's type doesn't look compatible with flatMap there to me.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to do exactly that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968345/un-optioning-an-optioned-option

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the use case for monad transformers, see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) for an explanation in Haskell and [here](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2011/07/monad-transformers-in-scala.html) for a discussion in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic method for dealing with `Option` chains is to use for-comprehensions and a `getOrElse` call.

```
val a = for {
    val temp <- f(param)
    val result <- Some(g(temp))
} yield result getOrElse <Default Here>
```

There's no getting around either having a default or raising an exception if you are going to categorically unpack the `Option` since `f` can return `None` and `g` can't accept that.